# Implement mouse interaction on custom control based on FrameworkElement

Tags: wpf, controls

This is just example to learn from.

I want create custom control with completely different looks. Hence, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview, I derive from `FrameworkElement`
and override `OnRender` method, also `OverriderMesure` and `ArrangeOverride` if needed.

Now I want implement mouse interaction, for example: on hover change color from red to blue. How I should do it?

```
public class Box : FrameworkElement
{
    private static Color defaultColor = Colors.Red;
    public static DependencyProperty ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Color", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(Box),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(defaultColor), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public SolidColorBrush Color
    {
        get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(ColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorProperty, value); }
    }

    static Box()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Box), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Box)));
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        // It's just example, I know shape is wayyy too simple to involve custom render.
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Color, null, new Rect(0, 0, ActualWidth, ActualWidth));
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue); // Set to color
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Color = new SolidColorBrush(defaultColor); // Back to default
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
       ...
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

So far I deduce:
Normally, if I had derive from `Control`, I would have use VSM for this. Unfortunately VSM isn't available until `ControlTemplate` hierarchy tree, so controls which have `Template` property. So if I decided to draw my control by myself I need use for this Routed Events, in this particular example `OnMouseEnter(MouseEventArgs)`, `OnMouseLeave(MouseEventArgs)` and some dependency property, like code above.

It this right approach? Please remember it's for learning purpose so `FrameworkElement` as base is obligatory.

I can see some drawbacks, becouse If we want control onHover color (in code above is harcoded to blue) I need mess around with code behind, or create another dependency property for this.

Comment: As a note, a property of type Brush should not be called "Color". Better call it Foreground or Background, as usual. Note also that `new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)` is redundant. There is the Brushes class, which has `Brushes.Blue`.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, you probably have right, name isn't accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately VSM isn't available until ControlTemplate hierarchy tree, so controls which have Template property.

This it not true.

You can use VSM normally, with some small changes. Read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples. Take a closer look on example.